# Does nginx support http2 over upstream servers?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, http2

I have been trying to configure http2 in nginx. I am trying to configure nginx as reverse proxy. I am sending http2 on front end to nginx server, it seems to be working fine, however when the request is proxied to the upstream server, nginx is not adding alpn extension during TLS handshake

Here is my proxy configuration

```
     location / {
             proxy_pass https://example.com/;
             proxy_ssl_certificate    "path_to_certificate";
             proxy_ssl_certificate_key     "path_to_key";
             proxy_ssl_protocols           TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
             proxy_ssl_ciphers             HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
             proxy_ssl_verify off;
    }
```

So I want to know does nginx support http2 on backend(upstream servers)? if yes from which version of nginx does it support?. Any help is much appreciated

I was trying to establish http2 connection to upstream servers from nginx. I expected nginx to negotiate http2 with the upstream servers

Comment: I unfortunately don't have a solutions answer for you, however the YES it does support upstream HTTP/2 . [Here is an old article](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-1-13-10-grpc/) introducing the opensource upstream gRPC support. you will be able to find clues to the correct solution from there.

Answer (score 4):

NGINX does not support "HTTP/2 to the backend". This is evident from [documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_http_version). The maximum HTTP version to the backend is 1.1.

There's actually little sense in adding such support. The primary feature of HTTP/2 is requests multiplexing. When you deal with HTTP proxying, the frontend NGINX routes *a request* to a matching location in backend. So when we talk about HTTP proxying, this level doest traffic inspection on the HTTP level in order to inspect headers, URIs to route requests appropriately. Thus it's always about inspecting a single request and routing it somewhere, multiplexing hardly applies here.

Even if you were to switch to a layer above that, which is TCP (and thus, `stream` module of NGINX), NGINX does not support this either. The stream module of NGINX can't negotiate ALPN protocol. ([reference](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/faster-web-server-stack-powered-by-unix-sockets-proxy))

Angie, a fork of NGINX, is capable of HTTP/2 and HTTP/3 to the backend servers. From [its official page](https://angie.software/en/#features):

> Supporting HTTP/3 for client connections, as well as for proxied server connections, with the ability to independently use different protocol versions (HTTP/1.x, HTTP/2, HTTP/3) on opposite sides.